# Mp4Parser output video not playing in any player

Tags: android, video, mp4parser

I am trying to replace the audio of an mp4 video. I have a mp4 source file and a .aac audio file. Mp4 file I am recording from native android MediaRecorder following is my code used for recording mp4 video.

```java
 public void initRecorder(File saveToFile, int displayWidth, int displayHeight,
                             int desiredWidth, int desiredHeight, int orientationHint,
                             MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener,
                             MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener)
            throws IOException {

        MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

        mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);

        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setInputSurface(mSurface);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);

        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(12000000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);

        if(desiredWidth > desiredHeight){
            float desiredAspect = 1080.0f / 2280.0f;

            if(desiredWidth > 2280 || desiredHeight > 1080){
                float aspect = (float) desiredHeight / desiredWidth;
                if(aspect > desiredAspect){
                    desiredHeight = 1080;
                    desiredWidth = (int) Math.floor(desiredHeight / aspect);
                } else {
                    desiredWidth = 2280;
                    desiredHeight = (int) Math.floor(desiredWidth * aspect);
                }
            }
        } else {
            float desiredAspect = 2280.0f / 1080.0f;

            if(desiredWidth > 1080 || desiredHeight > 2280){
                float aspect = (float) desiredHeight / desiredWidth;
                if(aspect > desiredAspect){
                    desiredHeight = 2280;
                    desiredWidth = (int) Math.floor(desiredHeight / aspect);
                } else {
                    desiredWidth = 1080;
                    desiredHeight = (int) Math.floor(desiredWidth * aspect);
                }
            }
        }

        mDesiredHeight = desiredHeight;
        mDesiredWidth = desiredWidth;


        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mDesiredWidth, mDesiredHeight);

        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientationHint);

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(saveToFile.getPath());
        mediaRecorder.prepare();

        mMediaRecorder = mediaRecorder;

    }
```

Above MediaRecorder object is being used to generate mp4 video file.
I downloaded .aac file from some internet source & I don't know its bit-rate, encoding etc.
following code I am using for merging/mixing .aac with mp4.

```java
Movie m = MovieCreator.build(video);
List nuTracks = new ArrayList<>();
for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
        if (!"soun".equals(t.getHandler())) {
        nuTracks.add(t);
        Log.d(TAG,"found video track");
        }
    }
Track nuAudio = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(audio));
Track crop_track= CropAudio(video,nuAudio);
nuTracks.add(crop_track);
m.setTracks(nuTracks);
Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);
FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(output)).getChannel();
mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
fc.close();
// sending final output file to player.
```

output file is not playing in some players and playing without audio in some player. I tried to play output file in ubuntu video player as well but there also it could not work. I am not sure whats wrong I am doing but suspecting that it could be different encoding issue but not sure how to deal with that. Any ideas/suggestions will be helpful.

[Input-mp4_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bm3KnF8G3MjUw4rL8Rfjxgkxg7NLGamK/view?usp=sharing)
[input-aac-file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fj1nqZ7sEvRBFFLbxPnWR4JpP17vL1ue/view?usp=sharing)
[Output-file-getting-from-mp4parser-not-paying-in-many-players](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nRg7auJ6oTPOFwZOfRrwzAjpx6JHzWdm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Provide a short video file for bytes checking...

Comment: @VC.One Thankyou for your response I updated links to inputs and output files.